# How to find the partition function of the $1$D Ising model?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, ising-model, partition-function

I am trying to solve a problem that requires finding a partition function.

**Question:**

Consider a one-dimensional Ising model with $N$ spins at very low temperature. Let there be $r$ spin flips with each costing energy $2J$. The total energy of the system is $E=-NJ+2rJ$ and the number of configurations is $C(N, r)$, where $r$ varies from $0$ to $N$. Find the partition function.

**Solution:**

\begin{aligned}Z=\sum ^{N}_{r=0}C\left( N,r\right) e^{-\beta \left[ -NJ+2rJ\right] }\\
\Rightarrow Z=e^{\beta NJ}\sum ^{N}_{r=0}C\left( N,r\right) e^{-2\beta rJ}\end{aligned}

Let $e^{-2\beta J}=x$. Then $e^{-2\beta rJ}=x^{r}$.

\begin{aligned}\therefore Z=e^{\beta NJ}\sum ^{N}_{r=0}C(N, r)x^{r}\\
\Rightarrow Z=e^{\beta NJ}\left( 1+x\right) ^{N}=\left( e^{\beta J}+e^{\beta J}e^{-2\beta J}\right) ^{N}\\
\Rightarrow Z=\left( e^{\beta J}+e^{-\beta J}\right) ^{N}\\
\Rightarrow Z=\left( 2\cosh\beta J\right) ^{N}\end{aligned}

However, the answer provided is $Z=\left(\cosh \beta J\right) ^{N}$. How do we remove the factor $2$? Was the given answer wrong, or is there something that I still need to do?

Comment: The factor of 2 drops out of any physical predictions. People might drop it from the expression for the partition function for this reason.

Comment: I would add two things: 1) There should be $\cosh(\beta J)$ instead of $\cos(\beta J)$. 2) Are you working with open or closed boundary conditions? If it is open boundary condition, then the number of "spin-flips" can only be ${N-1}$ (and not $N)$, however there is an extra $2$ factor as for each "spin-flip pattern" there are two types "spin patterns", and then we get back well-know formula for the partition function $Z=2 (2\cosh (\beta J ))^{N-1}$